# How to replace an array with key-value data structure in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, key-value

I have declared an array in typescript and pushing values in the array as follows:

```
hostArray: any = [];

for (const data of this.tableData) {
  data.hostName = data.hostName == null ? 'Not Available' : data.hostName;
  this.hostArray.push(data.hostName);
}
```

Instead of pushing data in array, I want to change it to a `map` having `key` `value` pair such that `key` is `hostName` and `value` is `hostName`
This way, if I want to add another values in future for the same `key(hostName)` then I can easily find it using the key and add new value.

Please suggest if there could be a better `data structure` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Use an object `hosts = {}` and add `hosts[data.hostname] = data.hostname`. Alternatively a map `hosts = new Map()` then `hosts.set(data.hostname, data.hostname)`.

Comment: Mapping a string to itself sounds more like you want a `Set`, not a key-value structure.